# Flex Chart making Browser unresponsive

Tags: performance, flash, apache-flex, adobe, flash-builder

I have an flex-3 swf(simple line chart- that use http-service to get data for the chart)

and in my application ,in one page i have to list multiple rows of data( normally more than 30 rows), for each row i have to include this chart .

problem is when the numbers of rows are increasing at the loading time the browser went in to unresponsive state.

I want to know how to  handle this situation , is there any better way to show the single flex-3 chart multiple times in a page.

Answer (score 0):

Charts are heavy components. I don't recommend using too much instances. Also, you seem to just create more and more instances of time, that is not the best solution. You should reuse instances. Check out how Flex uses item renderer.

Comment: thats the client requirement. i can't change that.. i need to add swf file for each row.

Comment: Well, since you have to create instances ... you could try creating them in different frames. But that would mean, you'd have to coordinate the creation and the charts would appear one after another.